# 403 Forbidden trying to access folder on browser

Tags: linux, apache, centos, localhost, httpd.conf

I have a folder in ~/Documents/WebD/ named Tarea which have a public_html folder inside, to access it I have tried creating a virtual host in a thousand ways but it didn't work, now I'm trying to get there creating a Symlink from tarea to /var/www/html/tarea, and accessing via localhost/tarea/public_html but y get

```
    Forbidden
    You don't have permission to access /tarea on this server.
    Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at localhost Port 80
```

I tried a lot of different ways named on forums, changing httpd.conf, give permissions to apache, etc, but non of them worked

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It could be SELinux preventing Apache from accessing those files. I would try switching SELinux into permissive mode and seeing if your permissions open up. You can read more about SELinux and Apache [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Managing_Confined_Services/chap-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server.html).

To put SELinux into permissive mode, do:

```
echo 0 > /selinux/enforce
```

To put SELinux back into enforcing mode, do:

```
echo 1 > /selinux/enforce
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have already checked Persmissions for /tarea folder. The User which is running the Apache server should have read/write permissions on the specific directories.

Comment: this is what ls -ld returns me: 
drwxrwxrwx. 6 apache apache 4096 Jun 12 14:32 tarea